# C Linked List: Inserting nodes to the end

Tags: c++, matrix, linked-list

I'm having trouble with implementing the code as a linked list and would appreciate some insight into where to go with my code. I am reading from a file to print out two sparse matrices (even sides) to store as linked lists. The output that I am getting is as if the matrices are all 1's, e.g.

```
Matrix 1: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

when the output should be getting:

```
Matrix 1: 1 2 3 4 5
```

if from a matrix that looks like this:

```
0 1 0 0 
2 0 0 3 
0 0 0 0
0 0 4 5
```

I have a feeling that it is an issue with my AddNodes function, but I am unsure.

```
struct Node{
    int row;
    int column;
    int value;
    Node *next;
};

Node *A, *B;

void ReadMatrix(Node *& listpointer, char * file_name);
void AddNode(Node *& listpointer, int row, int col, int nvalue);
//void PrintLL(Node *& listpointer);
//void AddMatrices(Node *& A, Node *& B, int row, int column);
//void PrintMatrix(Node *& listpointer);

int main(){
    A = NULL;
    B = NULL;
    ReadMatrix(A, (char*)"matrix1.txt");
    ReadMatrix(A, (char*)"matrix2.txt");
    PrintLL(A);
    PrintMatrix(A); //etc
}
```

Initiation of the Linked List.

```
void ReadMatrix(Node *& listpointer, char * file_name){
   //reads a matrix from a file
   int col = 0, row = 0, value = 0; 

   FILE *input = NULL;
   input = fopen(file_name, "r");

   if(input == NULL){
   printf("Cannot open file %s. Exiting.\n", file_name);
   exit(0);
   }
   //reads the matrix dimensions from the first line 
   fscanf(input, "%d %d", &row, &col); 
    printf("%d %d\n", row, col);
   //read matrix 
   for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
       for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
       //reads each value from this row (second line onwards)
       fscanf(input, "%d", &value);
       if(value == 0) continue;
       //Include your own add_node(a, i, j, value); function here
       AddNode(listpointer, i, j, value);
       //The next line is for debbuging, it can be commented later
       printf("Element at (%d %d) is different than zero and it is: %d\n",i,j,value);
       }
   }
   fclose(input);
}
```

The Add Node function.

```
void AddNode(Node *& listpointer, int row, int col, int nvalue){
   Node * temp;
   temp = new Node;
   temp->row = row;
   temp->column = col;
   temp->value = nvalue;
   temp->next = listpointer;
   listpointer = temp;
   if(listpointer->next == NULL){
       listpointer->next = temp;
   }else{
      Node * current = listpointer;
      while (true){
          if(current->next == NULL){
              current->next = temp;
              break;
          }
      }
   }
   temp->next = NULL;
   return(0);
}
```

Comment: If this is C what are the ampersands in the function definitions about? In C++ you can pass values by reference but not in C unless I have missed out on something.

Comment: `void` functions doesn't return a value. Your code didn't meet a compiler yet.

Comment: What is the point of all the code after `listpointer = temp`?  If you had just stopped there, you would at least have a functioning list (with entries in reverse order).

Comment: it isn't functioning, without that code it just prints out a bunch of 1's just the same as with it there. I did stop there but it just wasn't working so I tried to alter it. I'm really confused

Answer (score 2):

AddNote is too complicated and contains an endless loop. At first, I advise to use std::list. An element can be added to the end of list using push_back method. Then, if you really need to have your own implementation of a list, you have several options:

1. Remember not only the beginning of a list, but the last node too. In this case adding to the end will be simple.
2. Or you can add new elements to the beginning, and then revese the list after all elements have been added.